# Kotlin equivalent of php's $object->{$key}

Tags: php, kotlin

I have the following Kotlin class:

```
class Program {
    @SerializedName("hrs0")
    var nHrs0: Int? = null
    @SerializedName("hrs1")
    var nHrs1: Int? = null
}
```

I need to reference a variable from this class, but I only have the variable name as a string.  Normally, I would use it as so:

```
Program.nHrs0 = 5;
```

I need to be able to assign that value, but I only have the string equivalent of the variable's name.  In php, I would do something like this:

```
$program->{$variableName}
```

How can this be done in Kotlin:

```
variableName = "nHrs0"
Program.{variableName}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Just wanted to check if you tried the technique in my answer? Was anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would use a **Map** and after apply values to **Program**:

```
// create Map
val programMap = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()
// apply value to key
programMap["nHrs0"] = 5

val program = Program()
// get value from key
program.nHrs0 = programMap["nHrs0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Kotlin reflection API. The first step is to add the Kotlin reflection runtime to your project since it is not included by default because of its size/overhead and relatively rare use. I Use Kotlin `1.3.50` which is the latest version right now. Change to the version you use if you use an older version:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50'
```

This is how you use this API in this case:

```
// Obtain a reference to the nHrs0 member
val nHrs0Member = Program::class.members.find { it.name == "nHrs0" }

// Since it is a property (var), we can and must cast it to
// KMutableProperty to use it
val nHrs0Property = nHrs0Member as KMutableProperty

// Kotlin properties are not really JVM fields. They consists
// of a getter (for 'val' and 'var') and a setter (only for
// 'var'). So to set this property, we need to obtain a reference
// to the setter
val nHrs0Setter = nHrs0Property.setter

// Create an instance to perform our operations on
val p = Program()

// Use our setter to set the property "nHrs0" on
// instance 'p' to 5
nHrs0Setter.call(p, 5)

// Prove that the property was set
println("p.nHrs0=${p.nHrs0}") // Prints p.nHrs0=5
```

For more information on how properties work in Kotlin, refer to the official docs on [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html). For more information on the reflection API, refer to the official docs on [Reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html)